# Getting error bundle.js:39454 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined using MERN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I am using the MERN stack and can't seem to figure out why this is happening. I have a list of post that show up just fine. When I click a post I get `Cannot read property 'email' undefined` inside the console. But if I hit refresh everything works just fine and that post shows up with all the working issues.

I was able to pinpoint the error to my `renderComments()` function. That is where everything is showing up undefined at.

**EDIT :** I think I found out what is happening, but I am not sure why it is happening. Before the rendering happens the comment that is created in the array.map function is only the comment ID. Only when the component renders is the comment an actual full object with all its properties. I will post the back-end to show how I am getting the comments on the post to help out.

It was asked to show a console.log of post before the array.map function. As this does point out what I said in the edit I will go ahead and show below to help.

[image]

**Post controller with comments:**

```
exports.getOnePost = function(req, res, next) {
  Posts.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundPost) {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    } else {
      res.json(foundPost);
    }
  });
}
```

**Post and Comment models:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var postsSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    content: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "user"
        },
        email: String
    },
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "comments"
        }
    ]
});

var Posts = mongoose.model("posts", postsSchema);

module.exports = Posts;
```

---

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var commentSchema = new Schema({
    text: String,
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        email: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("comments", commentSchema);
```

**Post_show page:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions/posts_actions';
import * as actionsIndex from '../../actions/index';
import * as actionsComments from '../../actions/comments_actions';

class ShowPosts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onDeleteClick = this.onDeleteClick.bind(this);
    this.deleteComment = this.deleteComment.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.getOnePost(id);

    if(this.props.auth) {
      this.props.getUser();
    }
  }

  renderButtons() {
    const { post } = this.props;

    if(!this.props.user) {
      return ( <div></div> );
    }

    if(this.props.auth) {
      if(this.props.user._id === post.author.id) {
        return (
          <div>
            <button
              onClick={this.onDeleteClick}
              className="btn btn-danger"
              >
              Delete
            </button>
            <Link
              to={`/posts/${post._id}/edit`}
              className="btn btn-success"
              >
              Edit
            </Link>
          </div>
        )
      }
    } else {
      return (
        <div></div>
      )
    }
  }

  renderCommentsButtons(comment) {
    const { post, user, auth } = this.props;

    if(!user) {
      return (<div></div>);
    }

    if(auth) {
      if(user._id === comment.author.id) {
        return (
          <div>
            <button
              onClick={() => this.deleteComment(comment)}
              className="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
              Delete
            </button>
            <Link
              to={`/posts/${post._id}/comments/${comment._id}/edit`}
              className="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              Edit
            </Link>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
  }

  renderComments() {
    const { post } = this.props;

    return post.comments.map((comment) => {
      return (
        <li className="list-group-item" key={comment._id}>
          <div>
            {comment.text} : {comment.author.email}
          </div>
          {this.renderCommentsButtons(comment)}
        </li>
      );
    });
  }

  deleteComment(comment) {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    const {user, post, auth} = this.props;

    if(!user) {
      return (<div></div>);
    }

    if(auth) {
      if(user._id === comment.author.id){
        console.log(comment._id, '-', post._id);
        // this.props.deleteComments(id, comment._id, () => {
        //   this.props.history.push(`/posts/${post._id}`);
        // });
      }
    }
  }

  onDeleteClick() {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;

    if(!this.props.user) {
      return (<div></div>);
    }

    if(this.props.auth) {
      if(this.props.user._id === this.props.post.author.id) {
        this.props.deletePost(id, () => {
          this.props.history.push("/posts");
        });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { post } = this.props;

    if (!post) {
      return <div> Loading...No Post</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/posts">Back To Post</Link>
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        <p>{post.content}</p>
        <p>created by: {post.author.email}</p>
        <ul className="list-group">
          {this.renderComments()}
        </ul>
        {this.renderButtons()}
        <Link
          className="btn btn-warning"
          to={`/posts/${post._id}/comments/new`}>
            Comment
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ posts, auth, user }, ownProps) {
  return {
    post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id],
    user: user,
    auth: auth.authenticated
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({...actions, ...actionsIndex, ...actionsComments}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShowPosts);
```

**Post**

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import * as actions from '../../actions/posts_actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import _ from 'lodash';


class Posts extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAllPosts();
  }

  renderPosts() {
    return _.map(this.props.posts, post => {
      return (
        <Link to={`/posts/${post._id}`} key={post._id}>
          <li className="list-group-item">
            {post.title}
          </li>
        </Link>
      )
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="text-xs-right">
          <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/posts/new">
            Add a Post
          </Link>
        </div>
        <h3>Posts</h3>
        <ul className="list-group">
          {this.renderPosts()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    posts: state.posts
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Posts);
```

Comment: Can you console.log(posts) in renderComments?

Comment: I did that and I noticed that if I click the post from the post page which then sends you to that individual post I get 3 console.logs from post. The second two are the same, but the first has the comments array with only the comments ID. Which is related to the problem which I added in the edits. I think it has something to do with how I populate the comments.

Comment: Perhaps there's something wrong in the mapStateToProps? Can you log posts[ownProps.match.params.id] in there?

Comment: I get undefined 2 times then 4 objects that are all the same post. Something interesting that I wanted to point out is that in all of these posts (which are the same post) the comments are all objects. None of them are just the ID. Its like my backend is not getting called somehow to populate the comments at first?

Answer (score 0):

This was a back-end problem. As stated in the edit the post first being rendered only had the comment ID for the comment instead of the full comment object. I believe what was happening is that the initial post was coming from `posts[ownProps.match.params.id]` which all that was doing was grabbing the singular post from the post on the client side.

If you look on the back-end I store the comments as objectIDs and then later on populate them when a call to `getOnePost` is called.

What I needed to do is populate the comments on all post before they get called that way the comments are already populated and aren't just IDs. So to fix this I did the following (I will also post all the other code needed).

export function that goes to the backend router:

**Old:**

```
exports.getAllPosts = function(req, res, next) {
  Posts.find({}, function(err, posts) {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    } else {
      res.json(posts);
    }
  });
}
```

**New:**

```
exports.getAllPosts = function(req, res, next) {
  Posts.find({}).populate("comments").exec(function(err, posts) {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    } else {
      res.json(posts);
    }
  });
}
```

**Here is the post model:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var postsSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    content: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "user"
        },
        email: String
    },
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "comments"
        }
    ]
});

var Posts = mongoose.model("posts", postsSchema);

module.exports = Posts;
```

Both models are already posted above.